# Why cookies appear in request header but not response header when visiting a new website?

Tags: cookies

[image]

This is a incognito window in chrome visiting oracle. Please notice that the request header already has cookie in the very request.

I also tried to use GuzzleHttp in php and postman. I can't get the cookie from anywhere.

Actually I am trying to crawl some other website, and that website has the  same problem. I can't get the cookie so I got rejected.

Isn't cookie something that the server returns to the browser? Why in this  case it is like the browse know the cookie in the first?

Comment: _“Isn't cookie something that the server returns to the browser?”_ - the server _can_ instruct the client within the response, that it wants to set a cookie - it doesn’t _have to_ though of course.

Comment: _“Why in this case it is like the browse know the cookie in the first?”_ - most likely simply because you visited that site before already, and the cookie was set then.

Comment: @04FS. You may try it and tell me what you get. I tried to clear cookies several times and still same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Http cookies are set once in a response by the server (with a `Set-Cookie` header), then they are included by the browser in each applicable subsequent request.
So it is perfectly normal that cookies your browser already obtained are present in the request but not in the response.

Cookies may also be set on browser side by Javascript, but that also can't happen before the first request (to at least retrieve that Javascript).

Comment: I know the basics of cookie & session. I asked my friend to try that 2 websites and still the first request in chrome debug tool already has the cookie. You may try it too.

Comment: @bijiDango Cookies don't come out of the blue. The very first request you make will never have a cookie in the request. Try to open an incognito window, open the network tools and then visit the page. The very first request will not contain any cookie. Cookies also don't have to be set by the `Set-Cookie`. They can also be set from JavaScript.

Comment: @Ivar. Very good tool the incognito window. I tried, and the `very first request` actually already contains cookie.

Comment: @bijiDango Then I doubt it is actually the very first request. Did you close all other incognito windows before you opened this one? Maybe you have some plugins installed? Also did you directly go to `index.html`? If not then at least there should have been some redirects before this request. (Try to select 
"All" instead of "XHR" in your filters) If I make a request, the `cookie` header is definitely not there. That being said it's very hard to replicate. I don't know where you are making your requests from but from, but from Europe we get a nice request whether we accept their cookies.

Comment: @Ivar Yeah you are right. I didn't noticed I only check the XHR part. Thank you very much.